# I need a text to respond depending on screen resolution

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am working with bootstrap in my project, I've been testing on big screens but now I am testing in a MacBook 13" and I am having a little issue with the font-size

this is in a big screen

[image]

and this second one represents the issue on the left

[image]

so how can I avoid it ?

Comment: `white-space:nowrap` or `&nbsp;`

Comment: when you use em, set the default font-size of the parent 2px smaller. or try it with vw/vh (viewport width / viewport height), instead of px, at the element that should get a little smaller on smaller screens

Comment: is just the resolution of the screen, is not zoomed or something like that. besides ```white-space``` is there something else to avoid it? is I put ```white-space``` it affects the rest of the table size? and what is that of ```&nbsp``` ?@j08691

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have a pen? You could problay use a css nowrap selector. I found this example on the w3schools website.

```
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp
p {
    white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: is just the resolution of the screen, is not zoomed or something like that. besides ```white-space``` is there something else to avoid it? is I put ```white-space``` it affects the rest of the table size

Answer (score 1):

Just going from the pictures, it appears your font is *larger* in the second image. Which is probably the opposite of what you're going for. Is it possible you have a rogue `font-size:` in a media query somewhere?

If the images are just zoomed differently, then I would suggest using media queries to make the font *smaller*. Or use the suggested `white-space: nowrap` but keep in mind that doing so might make the width of the table do unexpected things.

Another thing that just occurred to me: is the browser zoomed on the macbook? I suspect the root of your problem is that the font is larger, not that the screen is smaller.

Comment: is just the resolution of the screen, is not zoomed or something like that. besides ```white-space``` is there something else to avoid it? is I put ```white-space``` it affects the rest of the table size

Comment: I don't know that it is the resolution. If you're looking at both of images simultaneously on the same screen, a pixel should be a pixel and I'm seeing two different sizes for the text.

Comment: Anyway, media queries are probably the way to go. [per mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries)